# Eclipse ADT 21 not including dependent project in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, dependency-management

I have an Android app that depends on a non-Android-specific pure java lib defined as an eclipse project.  I have added it as a dependency using the Build Path/Projects tab, and checked it on Build Path/Order and Export.  But when I try to run the project I get logcat errors like this:

```
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): Link of class 'Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity$5;' failed
03-02 11:05:58.615: E/dalvikvm(2292): Could not find class 'net.meridiandigital.polltest.MainActivity$5', referenced from method net.meridiandigital.polltest.MainActivity.<init>
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 575 (Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity$5;) in Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity;
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3316: Limap/IMAPConnection;.noop ()V
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 471 (Limap/IMAPException;)
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x26
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY:  rejected Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity;.alarm ()V
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0026
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): VFY:  rejected Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity;.alarm ()V
03-02 11:05:58.615: W/dalvikvm(2292): Verifier rejected class Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity;
03-02 11:05:58.625: W/dalvikvm(2292): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lnet/meridiandigital/polltest/MainActivity;)
```

The dependent project contains the definition of all the `imap/` classes, and `$5` is an implementation of an interface defined in this library, so it definitely appears to be the culprit.

Any ideas why my project isn't being linked?

Comment: Take a look in the .apk file generated(you can find it in `bin` directory). Can you find the name of the referenced Java project in .apk in lib/ directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to ADT21.1 fixes this, so it may have been a bug in 21.0.